# Find first occurrence of every value in a column

Tags: pandas

Given a Pandas series I want to generate a new series that stores the index of first occurrence of the value in the series.

Example: Given

```
   A  
0  1  
1  2  
2  3  
3  2  
4  1
```

I want the output to be

```
   A  B
0  1  0
1  2  1
2  3  2
3  2  1
4  1  0
```

Comment: `df['B'] = pd.factorize(df['A'])[0]`

Comment: If the index is not of integer type then this poses a problem. I cannot do `df['B'] = df.index[pd.factorize(df['A'])[0]]` since it would lead to incorrect index.

Answer (score 0):

Let us try

```
df['B'] = pd.factorize(df['A'])[0]
```

Comment: If the index is not of integer type then this poses a problem. I cannot do df['B'] = df.index[pd.factorize(df['A'])[0]] since it would lead to incorrect index.

Comment: @djin31 df.merge(df.drop_duplicates().reset_index(),how='left')

Comment: `z = df.merge(df.drop_duplicates().reset_index(),how='left')` followed by resetting index of z to be same as df.index worked